# TypeError: an integer is required (got type str) when using image.resize()

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to use the slider widget to zoom an image in small ranges using float values. I have created the slider and function to zoom the image as below however I get the error "TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)". Any suggestions to get this fixed are welcomed.

```
def showImage():
    img = Image.open('image.png')
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img.resize((260, 220), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    img_label = Label(frame1, image=img)
    img_label.image = img
    return img

## function to zoom the image ##
def zoom_img(zoom):
    showImage()
    newsize = (img.size[0]*zoom, 
                img.size[1]*zoom)
    scaledImg = img.resize(newsize, Image.NEAREST)
    newImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(scaledImg)
    img_label.configure(image=newImg)

## scaler widget ##
var = StringVar()
zoom_scale = tk.Scale(root, variable=var, orient='horizontal', from_=220.0, to=440.0, length=100, resolution=20.0, command=zoom_img)

zoom_scale.place(x=1600, y=160)

## Error generated ###
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:/Users/DANIEL/Desktop/exp/fcnvmb/butt.py", line 218, in zoom_img
    scaledImg = img.resize(newsize, Image.NEAREST)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1780, in resize
    return self.convert('RGBa').resize(size, resample, box).convert('RGBA')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1784, in resize
    return self._new(self.im.resize(size, resample, box))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value that gets passed to the `tk.Scale` `command` callback is a string.  You need to convert it to a float.

```
def zoom_img(zoom):
    zoom = float(zoom)
    ...
```

### Followup

OK, here's a version that seems to work.  I assume you want to keep the image window a constant size, which means you'll also need panning.  I've filled in some details you omitted, but this should just cut-and-paste run, once you substitute your image file name.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def showImage():
    img = Image.open('7460.PNG')
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img.resize((260, 220), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    img_label = Label(root, image=img)
    img_label.image = img
    img_label.pack()
    return img_label

## function to zoom the image ##
def zoom_img(zoom):
    global newImg
    img = Image.open('7460.PNG')
    newsize = (img.size[0]*int(zoom), img.size[1]*int(zoom))
    scaledImg = img.resize(newsize, Image.NEAREST)
    newImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(scaledImg)
    img_label.configure(image=newImg, width=260,height=220)

root = Tk()

## scaler widget ##
var = StringVar()
zoom_scale = Scale(root, variable=var, orient='horizontal', from_=1, to=20, length=100, resolution=1, command=zoom_img)
img_label = showImage()
zoom_scale.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: And did you print the `zoom` value so you can see what you're actually getting?

Comment: I have modified my scaler code as follows ```zoom_scale = tk.Scale(root, orient='horizontal', from_=1, to=20, length=100, command=zoom_seis)```. when I print zoom and slide the scale, it prints the current scale value but my image is not increasing when I slide the scaler

Comment: You don't want to call `showImage` each time.  That will create a brand new `Label` control, while still leaving all the old ones in there.  Just reconfigure the first one you create.

Comment: I have removed ```showImage()``` call from the ```zoom_img()``` function and and made ```img``` a global variable in the ```showImage``` function to make it accessible in the ```zoom_img``` function, but when I slide the scale to 2, it increases the image but image turns white and when I slide to 3 and above image don't increase anymore.

Comment: I may have led you a bit astray.  What you have now will re-zoom the image from its previous zoom state.  You probably need to refetch the `img` and create a new `PhotoImage` from that to start from the original zoom.  Just don't create a new label.

Comment: I don't seem to get what you mean. Maybe a little demonstration may help.

Comment: Take the first two lines of `showImage` and copy them into `zoom_img`.

Comment: I should probably try this myself; there's a weird situation where tkinter doesn't keep a reference to the image, so you may need a global.  I'll followup.

Comment: Yes, seems to work in your modified code but the image window only increases in the width direction and not in the height direction.

Comment: That's odd, because for me the window stays a constant size (260x220).

Comment: I have been able to modify on it to suit my functionality. Thanks for your input @Tim Roberts